# Ignite with No eviction

Tags: ignite

In Ignite cache we are not able to store more than 1 Million records. Records are getting evicted whenever the count is more than 1 Million.

Ignite Configuration

```
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
              <property name="maxSize" value="#{30L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
              <property name="name" value="500MB_Region"/>
              <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
              </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000000"/>
        <property name="networkSendRetryCount" value="50"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                          <list>
                                <value>cluster.node.host1:47500</value>
                                <value>cluster.node.host2:47500</value>
                                <value>cluster.node.host3:47500</value>
                                <value>cluster.node.host4:47500</value>
                                <value>cluster.node.host5:47500</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="networkTimeout" value="10000000"/>
                <property name="joinTimeout" value="10000000"/>
                <property name="maxAckTimeout" value="10000000"/>
                <property name="reconnectCount" value="50"/>
                <property name="socketTimeout" value="10000000"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Cache configuration:

```
var cache: CacheConfiguration[Long, String] = new CacheConfiguration[Long, String]("NAME_CACHE")
cache.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)    
cache.setBackups(0)
cache.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true)
cache.setDataRegionName("500MB_Region")
```

We need the cache to store data upto 30 GB and move to Ignite native persistence when it exceeds the size. There should be no data eviction.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: You configured the maximum memory region size with 4Gb only.
It seems that you need to increase that value `<property name="maxSize" value="#{30L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>`

Note, when Ignite native persistence is enabled, data is stored both in memory and on disk.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Could you please clarify how you detect that data is evicted?

Comment: We checked that by storing more than 1 million records in the cache. After storing in cache we checked the size which should be greater than 1 million but it is always less than 1 million. And regarding size, we increased the size to 30 GB but still the same issue exists. Edited the post to have 30 GB.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Are you sure that all keys are unique?
Is it possible to create a simple reproducer pom based project (github)?